# K8s livenessProbe times out but not when run manually

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, livenessprobe

I am running workloads on an EKS cluster (v1.25.16-eks) and some of my pods get restarted after liveness probe times out, while the service running is completely fine:

```bash
Warning  Unhealthy  19m (x9 over 25h)     kubelet  Liveness probe failed: command "docker-healthcheck" timed out
```

`timeoutSeconds` is set to 1 second. This is `docker-healthcheck` content:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if env -i REQUEST_METHOD=GET SCRIPT_NAME=/health SCRIPT_FILENAME=/health cgi-fcgi -bind -connect localhost:9000; then
    exit 0
fi

exit 1
```

My hot fix is to increase `timeoutSeconds` which works well. But I cannot figure out why those probes time out as they are simple `exec` probes that make a localhost HTTP call. They certainly take much **less than 1 second when run manually from inside the container**.

I am running out of explanations and cannot seem to find EKS-specific reasons. I tried looking for a kubelet overhead for executing those probes but could not find any. Is there any reason why I observe this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that the application is not yet running when the probe is triggered? You can try increasing `initialDelaySeconds` for the probe (by default it's 0 seconds).

Comment: @VasiliiAngapov it could be, however the pod gets ready at some point. What I mostly observe is random restarts while the pod is already running and ready

Comment: That only means that sometimes for whatever reason the app is taking more than 1 second to respond. You can try increasing `failureThreshold ` or `timeoutSeconds`.